# $o_{p}(1) = O_{p}(1)$ (i.e., $X_{n} = o_{p}(1) \implies X_{n} = O_{p}(1)$, sorry for the abuse of notation)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

**Corrected from the first answer by NCh**

I am trying to prove $o_{p}(1) = O_{p}(1)$, here is an attempt, can someone help me whether I am correct.

$X_{n} = O_{p} (1)$ means

\begin{align}
\forall \epsilon>0, \quad \exists \delta(\epsilon)<\infty \quad \text { such that}, \quad  P\Big(\left|X_{n}\right| > \delta(\epsilon) \Big) <  \epsilon \quad \forall n
\end{align}

Now we have $X_{n} = o_{p} (1)$, this means

\begin{align}
 \forall \epsilon>0, \forall \delta>0, \quad \exists n_{0}(\epsilon, \delta) \in \mathbb{N} \quad \text { such that}, \quad  P\Big(|X_{n}|\geq \delta\Big)<\epsilon \quad \forall n \geq n_{0}(\epsilon, \delta)
\end{align}

So let us fix an $\epsilon$, and we can pick any $\delta$, call it $\delta_{p}$, then $\exists N_{0}(\epsilon)$ such that

\begin{align}
   P\Big(|X_{n}|\geq \delta_{p}\Big)<\epsilon, \quad  \forall n \geq N_{0}(\epsilon)
\end{align}

So this means $\forall n \geq N_{0}(\epsilon)$, $X_{n}$ is already bounded, now for $\forall n < N_{0}(\epsilon)$, define $\delta_{n}$ such that

\begin{align}
   P\Big(|X_{n}|\geq \delta_{n}\Big)<\epsilon
\end{align}

Now we can take $\delta := \max\{\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}, \ldots, \delta_{N_{0}(\epsilon)-1}, \delta_{p} \}$, then we have

\begin{align}
   P\Big(|X_{n}|\geq \delta \Big)<\epsilon, \quad  \forall n 
\end{align}

And the claim follows.

Comment: You may want to use something like $o_P(1)\subseteq O_P(1)$, because using $=$ for a non-symmetric predicate is weird.

Comment: Thanks man, I know this is really weird, but this is actually the standard way of writing, for example you can look [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=vWndCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=o+p+(1)+%3D+O+P+(1)+%2B+statistics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirnLalzO3mAhUM-6QKHQnbBcUQ6AEIOzAC#v=onepage&q=o%20p%20(1)%20%3D%20O%20P%20(1)%20%2B%20statistics&f=false)

Comment: The implication $X_n=o_p(1)$ $\Rightarrow$ $X_n=O_p(1)$ is not the same as  $o_p(1)=O_p(1)$. The inverse implication is not true, so @Gae.S. is completely right.

Comment: @ShaikhTanvirHossain I don't know the source, nor could I read it in full, therefore I didn't want to question your word. The analogies I can see with your $o_P(1)=O_P(1)$ (i.e. when $=$ is used between classes of random variables) are in expressions such as $o_P(1)O_P(1)=o_P(1)$, which is as consistent with the interpretation $$\forall X,( X=o_P(1)O_P(1)\leftrightarrow X=o_P(1))$$ as it is with yours.

Comment: @Gae. S., Thank you so much man, I am really sorry to randomly point you the source. You are right this is not an equivalence and I also I didn't mean that. But this is how you would find sometimes in the literature, so I followed the convention. Thanks a lot for clarity. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take $\delta := \max\{\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}, \ldots, \delta_{N_{0}(\epsilon)-1}, \delta_{p} \}$. If you take $\delta := \min\{\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}, \ldots, \delta_{N_{0}(\epsilon)-1}, \delta_{p} \}$, the inequality 
\begin{align}
   P\Big(|X_{n}|\geq \delta \Big)<\epsilon, \quad  \forall n 
\end{align}
is not right.

For $\delta \geq \delta_n$ the event $\{|X_{n}|\geq \delta\}$ implies the event $\{|X_{n}|\geq \delta_n\}$ and then 
$$
P\Big(|X_{n}|\geq \delta \Big)\leq P\Big(|X_{n}|\geq \delta_n \Big)<\epsilon.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the correction. Yes you are right. I corrected that, but with that do you think the proof is correct?

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct.

Comment: Just to be more clear, this line $ P\Big(|X_{n}|\geq \delta_{n}\Big)<\epsilon$ from the proof came from a feeling. But if someone asks me why? I don't think I have a convincing answer, can you please explain why from the assumption this may hold

Comment: For any r.v. $X$, cdf $F_{|X|}(x)$ has the unit limit at infinity: $\lim_{x\to\infty} F_{|X|}(x) = 1$. This property holds for any cumulative distribution function. Therefore $\mathbb P(|X| \leq x) \to 1$ as $x\to \infty$ and $\mathbb P(|X| \geq x) \to 0$. So for any $\epsilon>0$ you can choose $x$ s.t. $\mathbb P(|X| \geq x) \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: So I am assuming the CDF exists? Thanks for clarity

Comment: Cdf $F_{|X|}(x)=\mathbb P(|X| \leq x)$ always exists since $|X|$ is random variable.